# KMM Project obfuscate Kotlin before build framework

Tags: objective-c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

With KMM project, I can build compile code into a file aar for obfuscating code.
But I can't find the way to obfuscate code for objective-c after compiled code.

How can I solve it?

Comment: At this moment the question lacks significant details. What exactly do you mean by "obfuscating code"?

What do you want to obfuscate -- is it machine code or Objective-C header (if you are distributing the generated framework)?
Why do you want to obfuscate it -- what exactly are you trying to protect it from?

Comment: @SvyatoslavScherbina
I want to obfuscate machine code before gen to Objective-C header.
Our app have 2 layers that A and B.
A prefer to B. I want to public all code layer A and obfuscate layer B.

Comment: The compiler generates Objective-C header before it emits machine code, so your question is still not clear to me.

Comment: If it compiler generates Objective-C header so we have to obfuscate the header file, isn't it?